# Trying out HTML video tag, nothing happens

Tags: html, web, path, html5-video

Okay, so I am giving HTML5 a go, and seeing how easy it is to use the video tag.

Turns out not so.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="vid" poster="Rick-Roll3.png" width="640" height="480" controls autoplay>
            <source src="rick.webm" type="video/webm" />
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have written out the file above and saved as a .html file. For some reason, however, it doesn't work. No video will play.

However, if I use this source instead the video it points to does play

```
<source src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
```

I know the file rick.webm is on the server, in the same folder as the html file. Is there something wrong with my src path?

Comment: Does your browser support `webm`? And do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Yes, I am using Chrome. I see no errors in the console.

Comment: Actually, looking at the GET request, it seems to be cancelled for some reason.

Comment: If you post some headers we might be able yo help, but good that you got it narrowed down.

Comment: The Chrome Developer Tools show this: http://i.imgur.com/sRcCZCI.png

Comment: Remove poster and try again. I think poster is not available. display some error msg in case of failure in video tag.

Comment: @kongaraju unfortunately, that's not the problem. It loads the player fine, it's just there's no content to display. The poster actually does display fine.

Comment: <video id="vid" poster="Rick-Roll3.png" width="640" height="480" controls autoplay>
            <source src="rick.webm" type="video/webm" /> Video type not support in your browser.
        </video>

Comment: @kongaraju I have tried that now, and this is what comes up: http://i.imgur.com/Btnoss1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browsers use partial range HTTP requests (which should return code 206 for Partial Content) to download the sources in video elements. You seem to be running a local webserver or something equivalent based on your headers picture, so most likely the server you are using does not support these kind of requests properly, while the server hosting the external video does.

I personally use a simple [Express](http://expressjs.com/) (for [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)) static file server for simple testing, which supports the necessary range requests just fine. It's literally this simple:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express();

app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening on port 3000");
```

Run this with node, and it'll serve the contents of the public folder (and all its subfolders) at `http://localhost:3000/`.

Comment: This was the problem. I configured the server to serve webm files and the video now plays. Thanks!